# Why is the data not retrieved from axios Promise using await?

Tags: reactjs

I am making a post request using axios:

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8080",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
});

instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response
  }, async function (error) {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (error.response.status === 403 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      const access_token = await refreshAccessToken();            
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + access_token;
      return instance(originalRequest);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
});

const getToken = async () =>{
    const userData = {
      login: login,
      password: password,
    };
    const responce = await instance.post("http://localhost:8080/login", userData,{headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }});
    return responce;
}
```

Now when I'm trying to get an answer:

```
const data = getToken();
```

[image]

A Promise is always returned, which contains the necessary data inside, but how do I get just data without a Promise?

i also try:

```
const responce = await instance.post("http://localhost:8080/data", userData,{headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }})
.tnen((responce) => responce.data);
```

But nothing changes.

Comment: axios already return a promise, you don't have to use async await on it

Comment: Why does your code `return rest`? What is `rest`?

Comment: @jarmod misspell

Comment: @OmarZaoujal I tried to do as suggested in similar situations, but nothing has changed

Comment: Note: you don't need to provide headers when calling instance.post because instance already has the same headers. That's largely the whole point of using an Axios instance.

Comment: Try changing getToken to `return instance.post(...)` and then call getToken via `const response = await getToken(); const data = response.data;`

Comment: @jarmod Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245698/discussion-between-jarmod-and-omegon).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified example of how to make calls with Axios and get JSON responses:

```
const axios = require("axios");

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});
    
const postData = async (data) => {
  return instance.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", data);
};

// An async IIFE
(async () => {
  const response = await postData({ id: 100, title: "Yellow submarine" });
  const data = response.data;
  console.log(data);
})();
```

The printed result is:

```
{ id: 101, title: 'Yellow submarine' }
```